# how to force font down the css tree?

Tags: css, magento, fonts

I have a situation that I can't seem to figure out with CSS.
I have a sidebar category menu that I want to be a certain font.. but the other content when it is in the sidebar to be the standard font.
The issue is that the div structure looks like this.
...

```
<div class="col-left sidebar">
  <div id"sidebar-nav" class"block sidebar-nav-left codnitiveSidenavLeft">
    <div class="block-title">..</div>
      <div class="block-content">
```

Now what happens is that block-content has a font value in css which is the normal font.. when it is not under the class "block sidebar-nav-left coditiveSidenameLeft" then that is fine.. when it is under the "block sidebar-nav-left coditiveSidenameLeft" class then I want to use a special font called destroyregular.. here is what I have in the css.

```
.block .block-content {
    padding: 5%;
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
    /*font-family: "destroyregular";*/
    font-size: 100%;
    font: bold 12px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


 #sidebar-nav.block.sidebar-nav-left.codnitiveSidenavLeft
 {
    padding: 5%;
    font-family: "destroyregular" !important;
    font-size: 100%;
    /*font: bold 12px Arial, sans-serif;*/
    color: #E6E6E6;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

While container class"block sidebar-nav-left coditiveSidenameLeft" does have the destroyregular font, it is overridden by the block-content.. how can I force the destroyregular font down to the block-content only if it is under it?

Thanks in advance..

--Corrected typo in div... side-nav was corrected to sidebar-nav  sorry.. 
--Corrected typo #2!! arrgh..  #sidebar-nav.block.sidebar-nav-left codnitiveSidenavLeft

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

This selector:

```
#sidebar-nav.block.sidebar-nav-left.codnitiveSidenavLeft
```

Doesn't select anything in that HTML snippet you posted.  The ID and class names don't match.

UPDATE: With the corrected selector, what's going on now is that the font destroyregular is getting applied with very high specificity to the .block, but .block-content will not inherit it over something set specifically for .block-content jsut because the parent has high specificity.  This is how I would do it, same HTML and add this CSS:

```
#sidebar-nav.block.sidebar-nav-left.codnitiveSidenavLeft .block-content {
    font-family: "destroyregular";
}
```

This is not optimal.  I think it's overspecified. And probably you can get rid of the font definition on the other (overspecified) selector and move it to that one, but that depends on what you actually need.

Comment: You still have the classname that's different : `coditiveSidenameLeft != codnitiveSidenavLeft`

Comment: I can't type!   #sidebar-nav.block.sidebar-nav-left codnitiveSidenavLeft
I fixed the 2nd  typo.. still does not work, since the block-content overrides it!

Answer (score 0):

Change the sidebar and .block-content to this:

```
  #side-nav
     {
        padding: 5%;
        font-family: "destroyregular", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #E6E6E6;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

   .block-content {
        padding: 5%;
        font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

Comment: This does not work.. since the content is below the side-nav and overrides the side-nav... as I stated only if the content is under class sidebar-nav-left.codnitiveSidenavLeft do I want to use the destroyregular font.. the block-content is NOT under that class then I want to use just the Lato font..